# Saving dynamically generated checkbox state in a ListView

Tags: android

My ListView Item contains a TextView and a LinearLayout. The LinearLayout contains dynamically generated CheckBoxes, the number of the checkboxes can be different in each list item. I want to save the state of the checkbox when I scroll the item off the screen, and scroll it back to focus. Right now it's not being saved. Here's my code, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseModel> {

  private ArrayList<CheckboxModel> mCheckboxModels;

  private static class ViewHolder {

    TextView mName;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

  }

  public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BaseModel> baseModels) {
    super(context, 0, baseModels);
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    final BaseModel currentBaseModel = getItem(position);

    mCheckboxModels = new ArrayList<>();

    View currentRow = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (currentRow == null) {
      viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
      currentRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
      viewHolder.mName = (TextView) currentRow.findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
      viewHolder.mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) currentRow.findViewById(R.id.idCheckboxLinearLayout);
      currentRow.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
      viewHolder = (ViewHolder) currentRow.getTag();
    }

    if (currentBaseModel != null) {
      viewHolder.mName.setText(currentBaseModel.getName());
      viewHolder.mLinearLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

      int numOfButtons = currentBaseModel.getNumOfButtons();

      for (int i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++) {
        mCheckboxModels.add(new CheckboxModel(new CheckBox(getContext()), false));

        currentBaseModel.setCheckboxModels(mCheckboxModels);
        viewHolder.mLinearLayout.addView(currentBaseModel.getCheckboxModels().get(i).getCheckBox());

        final int j = i;

        currentBaseModel.getCheckboxModels().get(i).getCheckBox().setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                currentBaseModel.getCheckboxModels().get(j).setChecked(isChecked);
              }
            });

        currentBaseModel.getCheckboxModels().get(i).getCheckBox()
            .setChecked(currentBaseModel.getCheckboxModels().get(i).isChecked());
      }

    }

    return currentRow;
  }
}
```

Comment: store checkboxes count and its state in model class

Comment: Yes. And implement an onCheckedChange listener (or however it is called) to update the boolean value for the checked state in CheckboxModel.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, did you even bother going through my code?

Answer (score 0):

Do not do mCheckboxModels = new ArrayList<>(); in getView()

You have to do:

private ArrayList mCheckboxModels = new ArrayList<>()